# Images not showing on homepage after migration

Tags: plugins, images, urls, permissions

I have a website with one section not displaying images after migration, the src attribute returns empty urls, the site is intpro.co.zw and the section im referring to is on Latest Properties
What could be the problem, its only happening on this particular server.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using *absolute* paths in `src` attribute.

If your images are in your theme folder, you can use:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/yourImageFolder/yourImage.jpg" />
```

This way, URLs will be absolute even if you move your WordPress site to another server.

Comment: my src in the php file is like this: src="'.mk_thumbnail_image_gen($image_src, 260, 180).'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" title="'.get_the_title().'" />

Comment: So if `src` are empty that means your `mk_thumbnail_image_gen` function does not return anything. Search over there ! Test `$image_src` too in order to see if ot's not empty.